# Add a vector to every column of matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a  Matlab matrix: `data= zeros (22,5,82)`

During a process columns `1:4` are filled with data, for every level of dim (2) dim(3).

In column 5 I would like the values `[-2,-1,1:20]`, for every column in the 3rd dimension.  To put this in context, the data are from trials of an experiment:  dim(1) is samples, dim(2) is different data collected from each sample, and dim(3) are trials.

I've tried defining a variable: `sample=[-1,-2,1:20]'` and then using the code `data(:,5,:)=sample`, but this throws up the error:

> Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
>   subscripts

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to make the dimensions match. Matlab will not automatically broadcast this for you, you need to do it explicitly: `data(:,5,:)=repmat(sample,1,1,82)`

Comment: whoops - sample = [-1 -2 1:20]'

Comment: thanks Dan - I'll give that a go now :)

Comment: No problem, by the way if you make a mistake like that you should rather just edit your question than post it in the comments. I've edited it for you this time already.

Comment: Thanks Dan - worked with one amendment, in that I had to put the three dimensions in as such data(:,5,:)=repmat(sample,[1 1 82]), or it told me there were too many input arguments.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, I'm going to add that as an answer so you can accept it so that the question is marked as solved. Regarding your error, I do not get that error. What version of Matlab are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to make the dimensions match. Matlab will not automatically broadcast this for you, you need to do it explicitly:

```
data(:,5,:)=repmat(sample,[1,1,82])
```